# Can i give a tuple or list to a givens in the theano

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, classification, theano, supervised-learning

In theano, my funciton is showed below:

```
theano.function([index],classifier.errors(y),
gives={
    x:(trainset_x[0][index*batch:(index+1)*batch],trainset_x[1][index*batch:(index+1)*batch)
    y:trainset_y[index*batch:(index+1)*batch]},allow_input_downcast=True)
```

but it doesn't work. (the x in the givens is a tuple,is it right?)
Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `x`? Is it a scalar, vector, matrix, tensor3, etc? Also, why does `trainset_x` have two special entries in the first dimension (indexes 0 and 1)?

Comment: in fact, x is a tuple appended with two matrix, like this:(array1,array2),array1 has a shape of (4950,45,10), array2 has a shape of (4950,64). What i want to do is to give x :(array1(m:n),array2(m:n)) every time with m and n changes.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the line of code that declares `x`? i.e. the line that says something like `x = T.matrix()` or whatever it is in your case.

Comment: Thanks ,i have solved it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` value should be a symbolic expression that is of the same dimensionality as `x`'s dimensionality. For example, if `x` is a matrix then the symbolic expression here should also describe a matrix.

Comment: What i want to do is like this: there is a function with two input variables, but the first input variable is a tuple with two matrix (because the matrixs have different shape, so i can't combine them into one, but these two matrix both are the function input), i want to get the corresponding index value of the two matrix  as a batch to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by another way, instead of assigning a tuple, i add the parameters,i.e. there are x1 and x2 in the function.